# Не выполняются INSERT и UPDATE к определенной таблице PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, индексы

История такова.
На сервере кончилось место, и ребята, работавшие с проектом решили его почистить. В ходе очистки, они наткнулись на [статью](http://www.hivelogik.com/blog/?p=513) и криво очистили pg_xlog. В результате, PostgreSQL перестал подниматься.
Далее все это добро передали мне, я вытащил правильные значения для pg_resetxlog, чтобы БД хотя бы поднялась. В одной из таблиц были проблемы с индексами, из-за этого не работали INSERT-ы с ошибками "сделайте REINDEX". Не буду вдаваться в подробности по этому - но в итоге индексы были исправлены, эта таблица заработала.
Но возникла другая проблема. В одну из таблиц почему-то не работают INSERT-ы и UPDATE-ы. В логах - и postgres и бэкенда ничего. Просто висящие запросы, котоыре валятся по таймауту.
Запрос `SELECT pid, NOW() - query_start AS len, query FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state='active' ORDER BY len DESC;` возвращает мне вот такую картину:
[image: Активные запросы]
Не пойму, куда дальше копать.
П. с. место на диске в результате переиндексирования и прочих чисток, не связанных с postgres есть.

**UPDATE**
Я попытался убить все запросы, которые "висят" через `select pg_cancel_backend(3049);`
Большая часть успешно умерла, но остались 3 запроса, которые не убиваются.
Если кто подскажет безопасный способ их убить (возможно, они источник проблемы?)

**UPDATE 2** Ребутнул машину, висящие запросы убились. Но первый же UPDATE к этой таблице снова повис.

**UPDATE 3**
Что еще более странно, едсинственный запрос, который лочит таблицу (смотрел через запрос `SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT GRANTED;`) - это запрос, который завис, а NOT GRANTED вернет пустой результат...[image: pg_locks]

Comment: Вы не рассматривали вариант дампнуть всё содержимое и восстановить на чистой установке?

Comment: Я с горем пополам сделал pg_dump сразу после проблемы с восстановления reset_xlog, но я не уверен, что он корректно все восстановит - да и долго это. Если не получится по другому, попробую этот вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо в таблице были какие-то проблемы с индексами. Из-за этого запрос работал неимоверно долго.
Я сделал `REINDEX TABLE clients_client`, убив предварительно все зависшие запросы. После этого запросы стали работать.

Answer (score 1):

Сперва-наперво: удалять руками что-либо из `pg_xlog` или `pg_wal` категорически нельзя. В принципе нельзя лезть в `data_directory` кроме как за `postgresql.conf`, `recovery.conf` или `postgresql.auto.conf`. Всё стальное - только для самой базы и трогать руками можно только если понимаете что это и как используется вашей версией СУБД. То есть быть если и не контрибьютером проекта, то очень близко.

> я вытащил правильные значения для pg_resetxlog, чтобы БД хотя бы поднялась

[Как гласит мануал:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgresetxlog.html)

> You should immediately dump your data, run initdb, and reload. After reload, check for inconsistencies and repair as needed.

Если уж вы запустили `pg_resetxlog` - по отличному замечанию разработчика postgresql более верно называемый [pg_please_corrupt_my_data](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20190429130337.GB22355%40paquier.xyz) - вы обязаны сразу после запуска СУБД вытянуть все данные любым способом, инициализировать через `initdb` новый кластер, записать восстановленные данные туда. И затем **вручную** проверять, а что же вы вытянули и какие там аномалии в данных есть. Потому что вмешательством в xlog базу уже сломали и сведений о консистентном состоянии данных нет. И даже не пытаться "чинить" и уж тем более продолжать жить на повреждённом после resetxlog кластере. То что кластер повреждён - никаких сомнений, других вариантов после "чистки" pg_xlog просто нет.